# Which exclude property prefix is used with JRPrintServiceExporter?

Tags: printing, jasper-reports

On reports that I export to PDF, HTML, CSV etc. you can exclude elements of the report through a property you set like this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.key.{elementKey}"/>
```

For reports that directly get printed we use the `JRPrintServiceExporter`. So is there an opportunity to exclude elements via the .jrxml file when the report will be sent to the printer immediately?

The jasperreports documentations and samples only showing the exclude-property with reports which get exported to files.

We use the jasperreports-library 6.1.1 in our software.

Comment: Did you check the source code of *JasperReports API*? I think it would be the simplest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Java Print/Graphics2D** use `graphics2d` see [package summary](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/package-summary.html)

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.graphics2d.exclude.key.{elementKey}"/>
```